# mysql - select rows which occur fewer/more than x months of the year

Tags: mysql

I've got a table of product sales. Each sale has an item code (eg a serial number), and a date.

```
item_code | date

a | 2013-01-01
a | 2013-01-18
b | 3013-02-10
c | 2013-03-05
b | 2013-04-09
a | 2013-06-04
a | 2013-07-22
```

From this data, I can see that part code 'a' is sold twice in january, once in june, and once in july. Part 'b' is sold once in feb, and once in april. And then part c is sold once in march.

I want to return the list of all parts sold, for example, across 2 or more months of the year. So this would return parts 'a' and 'b'. If I upped that threshold to >=3 months of the year, it would only return part 'a'. It doesn't matter which months. But part 'a' occurs in 3 distinct months, so it gets a score of 3. Part 'b', a score of 2.

I could handle this with PHP of course, but can I do it purely in mysql?

Comment: Use `COUNT()` with `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
SELECT item_code, COUNT(distinct MONTH(date)) as month_count from product_sales
GROUP BY item_code
HAVING month_count > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT item_code
FROM ProductSales
GROUP BY item_code
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT MONTH(date)) >= @threshold
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/810c9/3

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    pc.*,
    count(lpc.item_code) AS TCount
FROM product_sales as pc
INNER JOIN product_sales AS lpc ON lpc.item_code = pc.item_code
GROUP BY pc.item_code
HAVING TCount >= 2
```